# In Windows Command Prompt, how to get the last command that started with some letters?

Tags: windows, command-line, command-history

Let's say I entered a bunch of commands one after another:

```
rm blah.txt
pwd
ls
cd ..
cd blah
pwd
```

If I want to get "rm blah.txt" to appear again without typing the whole thing again, I can press <kbd>up</kbd> 6 times.

But is there a faster way? Can filter my command history based on some text?

Intuitively, I would like to just type in `r` and then press up to search through my command history for only commands that started with "r".

Comment: In bash it would be `ctrl-r  r m`. What about installing cygwin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hit `F7` to bring up a list of the last few commands, then you can hit the first letter to jump to the first matching entry.  Hit the same letter repeatedly to move up commands with the same first letter (working from newest from oldest).

[image]

Comment: ls? You're using GnuWin!

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Actually, I did it as a joke.  Glad you noticed. :)

Comment: `ls` is a command that I tend to always type when I first open `cmd`.

Comment: @Corey: `ls` and any other cygwin command can easily be run via the Windows  command prompt: you just need to put the cygwin bin directory on the path.

Answer (score 0):

On Win-XP (and maybe Win-7 too), type the first few letters of your command and press `F8` to see the most recent command that started with those letters.  If that's not the one you want, press F8 again, and so on.  If you enter the command you select without modification, then you'll be positioned in the command history at the point when you originally entered the command and can use the up- and down-arrows to select the preceding or following commands.