# Is there a way to preload previous commands into a cmd window without running them?

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, command-history

So that I can just press up and get a list of commands I would potentially wish to run?

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: https://serverfault.com/q/95404/422271

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Windows Command Prompt, how to get the last command that started with some letters?](https://superuser.com/questions/796538/in-windows-command-prompt-how-to-get-the-last-command-that-started-with-some-le)